# How is WAVA age grading calculated?

Tags: running, long-distance-running

WAVA (now WMA) age grading is a method of comparing your running (and maybe other athletic?) performance across ages and genders. Most places describe it as being relative to the world record performance for a certain distance in your age/gender category ([although not all](http://www.ridersite.org/SBTraining/WAVAtables4.pdf)).

However, I would like to know what it means to be further down the WAVA grading. Where is 0%? Is it the slowest performance ever recorded?

Is the range based on some sort of normal distribution? Is 50% WAVA some sort of average time for that age/gender category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand the WAVA (and WMA) age grading is calculated as

```
record-time/your-time
```

where the record-time is the best recorded time for the specified distance, gender and age.

So as an example assume you are a 48 years old male running half-marathon at 1:42:12 (me). Then you need to know the record time for the WAVA 2006 tables: 1:06:23. And you age grade is then

```
1:06:23/1:42:12 = 3983 seconds/6132 seconds = 64.96%
```

You can check with one of the many [age grade calculators](http://www.runnersworld.com/tools/age-graded-calculator) around.

With other words, the age grade tells you how well you are doing compared with the best for the distance *at you age*. 50% means you're running at half the speed of the best, 66% means you're running at 2/3 of the speed of the best.

So to get a 0% WAVA age grade, your finish time must be infinite... And 50% does not mean you are middle of the road, but just that somebody else runs twice as fast as you.

Comment: This makes total sense. And I guess in other words, it's an indication of your speed relative to the world record. 50% means you ran at half the speed the world record holder did?

Comment: yep, that is correct